# UITableView in a Modal dialog & heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

It's almost the first time I'm implementing a table view in my code. I created  a simple table view class and I did not use InterfaceBuilder for this part. I tried to use the method:
heightForRowAtIndexPath
I'm my class to changed the first row height size(in section 0) to 100 and for the rests it returns  self.rowHeight;
I also created my tableviewcontroller(a subclass of tableViewController) to show my table view in a modal dialog. I tried to present it in a modal dialog, when it appears in modal dialog, the row height size of first section(when it's suppose be 100) is NOT 100 .actually it is as the same size of other rows. 
If I use to add the same tableview to  another view in my app(not using modal dialog), it shows the first row height as 100. do you know what could be force the row height in modal dialog not to be as it set in the method heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Thanks,
Kamran

Comment: I just did the same in a modal view and it worked fine. One thing I found odd about your question was self.rowHeight?  Does your delegate class have a property called rowHeight? Because I would think that's supposed to be tableView.rowHeight.  Perhaps you can share the code for the implementation of heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: OK I copied the "heightForRowAtIndexPath" to controller class and it works fine! does controller should override these methods to see the right height? or I'm doing something wrong? my TableView class contains these methods but I need some of them in my UITableViewController to get all things properly??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you created a subclass of UITableView. So here's a rule I learned a long time ago. If you're subclassing UITableView or NSTableView, you're probably doing something wrong.  There is no magic here. UITableViewController is automatically setup to be the delegate and datasource for it's tableview.  And `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is a delegate method. So it belongs in the delegate class. Read over the docs for UITableView and Objective-C programming regarding delegate methods. Also, http://dbrajkovic.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/delegate-methods-there-is-no-magic-cappuccino-cocoa/

The point of delegate and datasource methods is to accomplish most customization of the tableview without having to subclass. If you're setting delegate = self and datasource = self, you're definitely doing something wrong. Even if you did HAVE to subclass UITableView, the delegate and datasource of the tableview should not be self.

Comment: you mean I don't need to subclass my view from UITableView? then how do you make the view and how you assign it to a UItableViewController? I'm really confused.. didn't find a sample code that doesn't use IB to make the view.

Comment: First of all, you don't need to subclass a view to create an instance of the view. `UITableView *tv = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMakeZero];` will create a tableview for you.  HOWEVER, if you'll read the UITableViewController docs, you will see that when you create UITableViewController using `initWithStyle:` If there is no nib associated with the table view controller, it will create a tableview for you

Comment: You do need to subclass UITableViewController. For example, `OLFeedbackViewController *vc = [[OLFeedbackViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];` is all you need to do to make a tableview of grouped style.  In this case OLFeedbackViewController is a subclass of UITableViewController.

Comment: The Overview of the docs says it all. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Well I changed the code and now I don't have a separate class for my TableView as doc says the controller generates an unconfigured one for it. Is any sample code that shows how to manage the disclosure cells, I mean with tapping on the ">" goes to next page, select an option from a list and bring back the data to tableView's cell?Thanks

Comment: You need the read the apple docs. Or go buy a book. You can't expect to learn everything about this here.